# Avoid create PR without file changes in the GitHub UI

Tags: github, branch, pull-request

I have two GitHub branches in which the difference is some commits (commit merge one to other branch) but there is no file changes.
It would be possible to avoid create PR without file changes in the GitHub UI?

Thanks a lot!